# Does Parallel.Invoke() create a new thread or use a thread from a thread pool?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I'm trying to understand threads in C#.
Whenever I pass the method in `Parallel.Invoke()` it create a new thread or use thread from a thread pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the [`Parallel.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke) uses the current thread, and threads from the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). That's because the default value of the [`ParallelOptions.TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.taskscheduler) property is [`TaskScheduler.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default), and the `TaskScheduler.Default` schedules work on the `ThreadPool`.

```
TaskScheduler defaultScheduler = new ParallelOptions().TaskScheduler;
Console.WriteLine($"defaultScheduler: {defaultScheduler}");
Console.WriteLine("defaultScheduler == TaskScheduler.Default: " +
    (defaultScheduler == TaskScheduler.Default));
```

Output:

```
defaultScheduler: System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler
defaultScheduler == TaskScheduler.Default: True
```

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread),
    () => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread),
    () => Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
);
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qA6u9Z).

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.Invoke` method uses a thread pool to execute the provided methods concurrently. A thread pool is a collection of pre-allocated threads that can be used to execute tasks concurrently. When you call `Parallel.Invoke`, it creates tasks for each of the provided methods and adds them to the thread pool for execution. The thread pool will then assign the tasks to threads in the pool and execute them concurrently.

Creating new threads can be a time-consuming operation. Using a thread pool allows you to reuse existing threads rather than creating new ones, which can save resources and improve performance.

Using a thread pool allows you to easily control the number of concurrent threads, as the pool has a fixed size. This can help prevent overloading the system with too many threads, which can negatively impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it works in steps.

1. You call `Parallel.Invoke()`.
2. After that a new `task` or `task`s gets created for the work that you want to execute.
3. Those `task`s get scheduled by [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) for execution.
4. TPL schedules these tasks for execution by assigning threads from the thread pool.
5. returns when all the tasks have finished executing.

So to answer your question `Parallel.Invoke()` does not create a new thread or get it from the thread pool. It's handled by `TPL`

If I've missed anything let me know.

This is my understanding of the topic.